# Does it help to have a try-catch around NSManagedObjectContext save?

Tags: core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I make some non-essential changes to the database in a background thread (shortly after app launch), and then merge them into the main context. The background thread can end up making a lot of changes, but I don't want the context save to trip up over some validation errors or some inscrutable Core Data exception in this background processing; especially since I use iCloud with Core Data, users can end up with nilled-out relationships and what not. I just want the app to keep running instead of throwing an exception and quitting.

In this case, does it make sense to have a @try-@catch block around the context save? Are there any performance or memory management issues with doing this?

Something like this:

```
@try {
        [context performBlockAndWait: ^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if ([context save:&error]){
                NSLog(@"Child context saved");

                [context.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
                    NSError *parentError = nil;
                    if ([context.parentContext save: &parentError]){
                        NSLog(@"Parent context saved");
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    } ....
```

My app ships to thousands of customers, so it would be great to know before-hand if this could cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Unless you can actually recover from the exception in a safe way, catching it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

What exceptions are being thrown?

Since `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` uses the `NSError` out-parameter pattern, I would generally expect it NOT to throw. However, the general pattern in Cocoa is that exceptions are "death" and not considered recoverable.

There are places in various system frameworks that throw and catch exceptions (which you can see by setting an exception-throw breakpoint in the debugger) -- I'm looking at **you** Cocoa bindings -- but generally speaking if an exception bubbles up to your app's code, you're already "dead in the water."

> Are there any performance or memory management issues with doing this?

These days, the performance penalty for a `@try/@catch/@finally` is pretty minimal (this wasn't always the case). There are memory management implications to be sure (which is probably why exceptions are generally "death" on this platform.) If you're using ARC and exit a scope by way of an exception being thrown, retains taken by ARC are **not** released. As described [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions):

> The standard Cocoa convention is that exceptions signal programmer
>   error and are not intended to be recovered from. Making code
>   exceptions-safe by default would impose severe runtime and code size
>   penalties on code that typically does not actually care about
>   exceptions safety. Therefore, ARC-generated code leaks by default on
>   exceptions, which is just fine if the process is going to be
>   immediately terminated anyway. Programs which do care about recovering
>   from exceptions should enable the option.

In short, there's probably no point in wrapping a context save operation in a `@try/@catch` block.